# storing integers in an array stores a random value

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm coding my own minesweeper game for fun in C++ (The language I'm most familiar with) and when I'm storing a constant in a 2d array, it sometimes ends up storing a random value.

Here's my code:

```
using namespace std;

Table::Table() {
tiles[16][16] = {0};
covers[16][16] ={1};


}//stores position of mines, covers, and values

//places mines on the board
void Table::placemines() {
    int minecount=0;
    int i = rand()%15;
    int j = rand()%15;
    while(minecount<40){
        if (tiles[i][j] == 0) {
            tiles[i][j] = -10;
            minecount++;
        } else {}
        i = rand()%15;
        j = rand()%15;
    }
}
```

and my main.cpp to display the values

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Table newtable = Table();
    newtable.placemines(6, 7);
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            cout << newtable.tiles[i][j] << ' ';

        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

and the output

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 -10 -10 0 0 1 -10 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 -10 0 -10 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 -10 0 0 0 -10 -10 0 -10 0 0 0 
-10 0 0 -10 -10 0 0 -10 -10 0 0 0 0 -10 0 0 
-10 0 -10 0 0 -10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 -10 0 1920169263 0 -10 0 0 
0 0 -10 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 -10 1651076143 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 -10 0 1819894831 -10 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 0 32 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-10 0 0 -10 0 0 0 0 0 0 -10 2 0 0 0 0     
-10 0 0 0 0 -10 0 0 0 -10 0 4 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
```

Can anyone tell what's going on? Thank you!

Comment: the code should not even compile.what happens to 6 & 7 in placemines(6,7)

Comment: Fill with zeros and add your mines afterwards.

Comment: I don't think `tiles[16][16] = {0}` does what you think it does.

Comment: If you want to access the index 0 to 15 of the arrays tiles and covers, then you need to apply modulo 16. If you apply 15, then you only cover array index 0 to 14.

Comment: Does not compile, as-is (via copy-and-paste).  I think the bug may be in the code not provided, or may be an interaction between the code provided and not provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much code missing, no declaration, no `placemines()` code

You have bug here:

```
tiles[16][16] = {0};
```

This statement sets some element of array, with indices 16 and 16, to 0. If your array defined as  `type tiles[16][16]`  that means you write into the Abyss and cause UB (because last element of array is `tiles[15][15]`).

If you have to initialize an array, use `std::fill` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill . For zero-intialization this works:

```
Table::Table() : tiles{0} {
```

Another bug possible:

```
int i = rand()%15;
```

You have to use array's size to cover the range properly.

PS. Avoid `using namespace std;` in global scope, pleeeese.